# Using UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator no longer loads SQL files from file

Tags: java, jdbi

I keep all my sqls in a separate `.sql` and use `@SqlQuery("db/my-dao/fetch-my-dao.sql")`.

Everything works fine, but as soon as I add `UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator` to the Dao interface, it can no longer find the file, and I just get a syntax error saying the string "db/my-dao/fetch-my-dao.sql" is not a valid query.

How can I get both to work?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on here.

UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator is used by jdbi v2, to load SQL from a [StringTemplate(v3)](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) group file on the classpath.

For instance, if you have file AccountDao like:

```
package com.foo;

public interface AccountDao {

    @SqlQuery
    @UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator
    List<Account> selectAll();
}
```

In this example, since the fully qualified class name is com.foo.AccountDao, SQL will be loaded from the file `com/foo/AccountDao.sql.stg` on the classpath. Notice the *.sql.stg part. Since we are using UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator we have to create *.sql.stg file in same class path. For ex: in `com/foo/AccountDao.sql.stg`

```
group AccountDao;

selectAll() ::= <<
    your query goes here
>>
```